# How does `[]=` work in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, methods

I have a class like below:

```
class MyClass
  def [](key)
    '[] stub'
  end

  def []=(key, value)
    '[]= stub'
  end

  def foo
    self[:foo] #=>'[] stub'
  end

  def bar
    self[:bar]= 'bar'#=> '[]= stub'
  end
end
```

Is there any way to rewrite `MyClass#foo` and `MyClass#bar` methods without `self`?

Comment: Why don't you try it and find out?

Comment: @pjs, i've tried, no results.

Comment: Please edit to clarify "...without self exist"? You obviously must reference `self`, explicitly (`self.`) or implicitly (using `send`, as @Stefan explains).

Comment: the problem is that when you write [ ] without context, ruby interprets it as an empty array. But what is wrong with using self to be explicit?

Comment: @Meier, I assume your question was intended for me. (If so, please include @Cary so I will be notified by SO). There are various situations where the inclusion of `self.` is required. You have mentioned one. Another is `self.class...` Writing just `class...` will cause Ruby to interpret `class` as the keyword used when creating a class. Also if `setx` is a setter for the instance variable `@setx`, and you write `setx = 4`, Ruby will create a local variable `setx` and assign it the value `4`. To use the setter you must write `self.setx = 4`. You can also write `send(:setx=, 4)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `send`:

```
def foo
  send(:[], :foo)
end

def bar
  send(:[]=, :bar, 'bar')
end
```

But I would implement `store` and `fetch` instead and define `[]` and `[]=` as aliases:

```
def fetch(key)
  # ...
end
alias_method :[], :fetch

def store(key, value)
  # ...
end
alias_method :[]=, :store
```

And call `fetch` / `store` instead of `[]` / `[]=` from within the class:

```
def foo
  fetch(:foo)
end

def bar
  store(:bar, 'bar')
end
```